# tensorflow can not be imported

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, jupyter

I recently created a new anaconda environment to install the latest version of Tensorflow. after that, I used the following command `conda install tensorflow.`
I reinstalled tensorflow using this command: `pip install --upgrade --no-deps --force-reinstall tensorflow`
the version of python I'm using in this environment is :
Python3.7.9.
when I want to import tensorflow it throws this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-d6579f534729> in <module>
----> 1 import tensorflow

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py in <module>
     39 import sys as _sys
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.tools import module_util as _module_util
     42 from tensorflow.python.util.lazy_loader import LazyLoader as _LazyLoader
     43 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py in <module>
     39 from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow as _pywrap_tensorflow
     40 
---> 41 from tensorflow.python.eager import context
     42 
     43 # pylint: enable=wildcard-import

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\context.py in <module>
     30 import six
     31 
---> 32 from tensorflow.core.framework import function_pb2
     33 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import config_pb2
     34 from tensorflow.core.protobuf import rewriter_config_pb2

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\core\framework\function_pb2.py in <module>
      5 import sys
      6 _b=sys.version_info[0]<3 and (lambda x:x) or (lambda x:x.encode('latin1'))
----> 7 from google.protobuf import descriptor as _descriptor
      8 from google.protobuf import message as _message
      9 from google.protobuf import reflection as _reflection

ImportError: cannot import name 'descriptor' from 'google.protobuf' (unknown location)
```

here is the list of packages installed :

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_tflow_select             2.3.0                     eigen
absl-py                   0.12.0           py38haa95532_0
aiohttp                   3.7.4            py38h2bbff1b_1
astunparse                1.6.3                      py_0
async-timeout             3.0.1            py38haa95532_0
attrs                     20.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
blas                      1.0                         mkl
blinker                   1.4              py38haa95532_0
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py38h2bbff1b_1003
ca-certificates           2021.4.13            haa95532_1
cachetools                4.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
certifi                   2020.12.5        py38haa95532_0
cffi                      1.14.5           py38hcd4344a_0
chardet                   3.0.4           py38haa95532_1003
click                     7.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
coverage                  5.5              py38h2bbff1b_2
cryptography              3.4.7            py38h71e12ea_0
cython                    0.29.23          py38hd77b12b_0
gast                      0.4.0                      py_0
google-auth               1.30.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0
google-auth-oauthlib      0.4.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0
google-pasta              0.2.0                      py_0
grpcio                    1.36.1           py38hc60d5dd_1
h5py                      2.10.0           py38h5e291fa_0
hdf5                      1.10.4               h7ebc959_0
icc_rt                    2019.0.0             h0cc432a_1
idna                      2.10               pyhd3eb1b0_0
importlib-metadata        3.10.0           py38haa95532_0
intel-openmp              2021.2.0           haa95532_616
keras-applications        1.0.8                      py_1
keras-preprocessing       1.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0
libprotobuf               3.14.0               h23ce68f_0
markdown                  3.3.4            py38haa95532_0
mkl                       2021.2.0           haa95532_296
mkl-service               2.3.0            py38h2bbff1b_1
mkl_fft                   1.3.0            py38h277e83a_2
mkl_random                1.2.1            py38hf11a4ad_2
multidict                 5.1.0            py38h2bbff1b_2
numpy                     1.20.1           py38h34a8a5c_0
numpy-base                1.20.1           py38haf7ebc8_0
oauthlib                  3.1.0                      py_0
openssl                   1.1.1k               h2bbff1b_0
opt_einsum                3.1.0                      py_0
pip                       21.0.1           py38haa95532_0
protobuf                  3.14.0           py38hd77b12b_1
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                      py_0
pycparser                 2.20                       py_2
pyjwt                     1.7.1                    py38_0
pyopenssl                 20.0.1             pyhd3eb1b0_1
pyreadline                2.1                      py38_1
pysocks                   1.7.1            py38haa95532_0
python                    3.8.8                hdbf39b2_5
requests                  2.25.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0
requests-oauthlib         1.3.0                      py_0
rsa                       4.7.2              pyhd3eb1b0_1
scipy                     1.6.2            py38h66253e8_1
setuptools                52.0.0           py38haa95532_0
six                       1.15.0           py38haa95532_0
sqlite                    3.35.4               h2bbff1b_0
tensorboard               2.4.0              pyhc547734_0
tensorboard-plugin-wit    1.6.0                      py_0
tensorflow                2.3.0           mkl_py38h8c0d9a2_0
tensorflow-addons         0.12.1                   pypi_0    pypi
tensorflow-base           2.3.0           eigen_py38h75a453f_0
tensorflow-estimator      2.3.0              pyheb71bc4_0
termcolor                 1.1.0            py38haa95532_1
typeguard                 2.12.0                   pypi_0    pypi
typing-extensions         3.7.4.3              hd3eb1b0_0
typing_extensions         3.7.4.3            pyh06a4308_0
urllib3                   1.26.4             pyhd3eb1b0_0
vc                        14.2                 h21ff451_1
vs2015_runtime            14.27.29016          h5e58377_2
werkzeug                  1.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0
win_inet_pton             1.1.0            py38haa95532_0
wincertstore              0.2                      py38_0
wrapt                     1.12.1           py38he774522_1
yarl                      1.6.3            py38h2bbff1b_0
zipp                      3.4.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0
zlib                      1.2.11               h62dcd97_4
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with that?

Comment: Were you installing these in the base environment? If so, I would recommend starting fresh and reinstalling Conda from scratch.

Comment: No, I installed it on an environment I had created before. @AMC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to mix conda and pip installations.

If you don't want to delete your environment and start anew, either:

- try running `conda remove tensorflow` to remove tensorflow from conda (if you want to stick with `pip`)
- try running `pip uninstall tensorflow`, then running `conda install protobuf` (if you want to stick with `conda`)

But the wisest course of action would probably be to start with a new conda/virtualenv environment, then running either `conda install tensorflow protobuf` or `pip install tensorflow protobuf`.

Comment: I'm going to need a bit more information. What did you try? I suggested 4 courses of action. What happened and what didn't work?

Comment: I tried all of them, it throws the same error. I installed Cuda toolkit 10.1 and 11.0 is it the cause of the problem?
I've read an article and some questions in StackOverflow that having both these versions installed on my machine can not be the source of the problem.